# How switch between pictureboxes?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have many pictureboxes in my project and would like to know if there is code that makes it easy to switch between them in C#, for example:

```
// I dont' want to have to do this all the time
pictureBox38.Image = slagalica.Properties.Resources.grn_tick;
pictureBox39.Image = slagalica.Properties.Resources.grn_tick;

// I want something like this
int n = 38
pictureBox(n).Image = slagalica.Properties.Resources.grn_tick;
pictureBox(n+1).Image = slagalica.Properties.Resources.grn_tick;
```

Is it possible? Any code is welcome.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Assign the same image to all pictureboxes? Or just 38 and 39?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through all controls and apply settings to those, which are pictureboxes:

```
foreach(Control control in Controls)
{
   if (control is PictureBox)       
      ((PictureBox)control).Image = slagalica.Properties.Resources.grn_tick;
}
```

Or you can create your custom picturebox and use it instead of default pictureboxes:

```
public class SlagalicaPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    public SlagalicaPictureBox()
    {
        Image = slagalica.Properties.Resources.grn_tick;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create list of Picture boxes. Then you will be able to write something like `pictureBoxes[0].Image=img;`

Answer (score 0):

Add them to a list and use the indexer, for example a `List<PictureBox>` or `PictureBox[]`:

```
var dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(imagePath);
List<FileInfo> images = dir.GetFiles("*.jpg", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
List<PictureBox> pictures = new List<PictureBox>();
foreach (FileInfo img in images) {
    PictureBox picture = new PictureBox();
    picture.Image = Image.FromFile(img.FullName);
    pictures.Add(picture);
}
```

Now you ca access the pictures by index, for example:

```
var rnd = new Random();
int imgIndex = rnd.Next(0, 38);
PictureBox img = pictures[imgIndex];
```

Or in a loop

```
for(int i=0; i<38; i++)
{
    PictureBox img = pictures[i];
}
```

**Edit**: If you just want to find all  `PictureBoxes` on your form, you can use [`Enumerable.OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) which filters and casts the controls accordingly:

```
IEnumerable<PictureBox> allPictures = this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>();
foreach(var pic in allPictures)
{
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely consider what Lazyberezovsky posts.  However, if you want to iterate through controls rapidly, you can also construct a control array.

You can easily do this:

```
List<PictureBox> list = new List<PictureBox>();
list.Add(pictureBox38);
list.Add(pictureBox39);
```

Then you can iterate through them as follows:

```
foreach (PictureBox pb in list) {
    pictureBox.Image = slagalica.Properties.Resources.grn_tick;
}
```

If you want to be more clever, you can even create an array with a specified size and do the same.

```
PictureBox[] pb_array = new PictureBox[50];
pb_array[38] = pictureBox38;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while(n <= (number of pics)){
n++
pictureBox(n).Image = slagalica.Properties.Resources.grn_tick;
}
```

Yes i know this is Objective-C, but you get the main idea